# How would you spell this Chinese name?

Tags: names

I met a young lady the other day who told me her name was "Jinyin".
That is how it's pronounced, but not necessarily how it's spelled.
In fact, I don't think that's how it is spelled at all.
Could someone tell me what would be the English spelling of this name?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too local to be helpful to other Chinese learners.

Answer (score 1):

Was she pretty? Can you get me her telephone number?! Haha!

Maybe it is 金云 = jin yun = gold cloud (yun can sound like yin sometimes)

金莹 = jin ying = gold shiny gem

Maybe she has a surname in front of this name, which she didn't mention, or maybe her surname is 金 = jin = gold (surnames come first in Chinese)

Comment: +1 for the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Jinyin is a valid pair of 2 syllables in Pinyin (the official Mandarin transcription) composed of jin + yin. Take into consideration, that you might have misheard one or both finals, so Jingyin, Jinying or even Jingying is possible. (the -n and -ng finals are pretty close to each other and one might occasionally confuse them).

Actually some Westerners also might confuse the j- and q- initials, so a name beginning with Q- is also possible.

Next time you meet hear, ask her to spell her name in Pinyin.

PS. I wouldn't bother trying to make a guess on the meaning or the characters of the name, there are so many possibilities. Ask her to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese has many homophones, so it's difficult to know the exact words if you just know the pronunciation without the context. For a girl name, Jinyin probably is 金银 or 谨茵. You'd better ask her how to spell her name next time. :)